# signal: aborted (core dumped), making a two sum pair from a vector

Tags: c++, for-loop, if-statement, vector, vec

This is the question I'm trying to solve:

> Write `findTwoSumPair`, which takes in a vector of integers and a
> target sum, and returns a pair that represents two *distinct* indices
> of elements that sum up to the target value (with indexes sorted).
> There are no explicit time complexity constraints here (i.e. algorithm
> just needs to work as intended). Also make sure to handle empty input.

This is my main:

```
  std::cout << "Q3" << std::endl;
  std::vector<int> q3Input1{0, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  std::pair<int, int> q3Out1 = findTwoSumPair(q3Input1, 6);
  std::pair<int, int> q3Out2 = findTwoSumPair(q3Input1, 10);

  std::cout << q3Out1.first << " " << q3Out1.second
            << std::endl;  // should output 1 3
  std::cout << q3Out2.first << " " << q3Out2.second
            << std::endl;  // should output -1 -1
```

And this is the function causing me problems:

```
std::pair<int, int> findTwoSumPair(const std::vector<int>& vec, int targetSum) {
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++){

    for(unsigned int j = i; i < vec.size();j++){
     /* 
      if(targetSum == vec[i]+ vec[j]){
      std::cout << vec[i] << vec[j];
      }*/
    }
  }
  return{vec[i],vec[j];
 // throw std::logic_error("not implemented");
}
```

I was given the main.cpp so I'd like to not change it and there are the relevant library headers to make it run.

It only shows "Q3" for some reason. I commented out the content inside the `if` block because that was giving me the "signal: aborted (core dumped)" error.

Comment: Check the variable used in the condition of your second for loop.

Comment: Think about the situation where you don't find two values that add up to `targetSum`. In this situation, what are the values you are returning? Are they inside the `vec`?

Comment: Also think about what you are returning here. does not look you are returning the values asked for by the question: `two distinct indices`

Comment: Do yourself the favor and extract a [mcve] from your code. Also include that in your question, so everyone can reproduce it without guessing. Further, compile with warnings enabled and make sure your code doesn't emit any. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

As well as the "typo" in your code, where you are testing `i` in the inner `for` loop instead of `j` (the code you currently have will run that inner loop forever), there are some other issues in your function.

First, that inner loop should start at `j = i + 1`, otherwise a match will be found when any *one* value is exactly half the target (in your second test case, it will find a match for `5 + 5`, giving index results of `4` and `4`).

Second, as soon as a match is found, the function should return the current `i` and `j` values; then, if the outer loop terminates without a match being found, we can return the required `{-1, -1}` signal.

Here's a version of your function with the aforementioned (and some other) issues fixed:

```cpp
std::pair<int, int> findTwoSumPair(const std::vector<int>& vec, int targetSum)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        for (size_t j = i + 1; j < vec.size(); j++) {// Start at i + 1 and test j (not i)
            if (targetSum == vec[i] + vec[j]) {
                return{ static_cast<int>(i), static_cast<int>(j) }; // Match found
            }
        }
    }
    return { -1, -1 }; // Not found.
}
```